A 1970’s TV show where a boy stands in front of stone wall and it grows over him
Does anyone remember a children’s (I think!) TV series from the 1970’s where in one episode a boy leans back against a stone wall or shallow cave and gets covered instantly with over grown ivy? I grew up in uk.
This image has stayed with me for life but I don’t know the show or anything else - only that it was weird and scary. I feel like he wasn’t dressed in normal clothes.
